# JSONKit invalid arguement when try to copy

Tags: iphone, ios6, jsonkit

I am parsing JSON data with JSONKit as NSMutableDictionary.

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableDictionary *jsonResponse = [self.responseData objectFromJSONData];

NSMutableDictionary *newData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[newData addEntriesFromDictionary:[jsonResponse mutableCopy]];
```

When i do this i am getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:]: dictionary argument is not an NSDictionary'
```

I am trying to figure out what is causing this problem. I know that jsonResponse is an object of JKArray from my other experience.

I need help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
id object = [self.responseData objectFromJSONData];
NSLog(@"%@", [object class]);
```

Most likely your response is an array instead of a dictionary.

---

If you really want to convert the array into a dictionary, you could do something like this, using a self-defined key:

```
NSArray *array = [self.responseData objectFromJSONData];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array forKey:@"posts"];
```

Though perhaps there are some better options if you could show me the contents of your array.

Comment: response is JKArray, like i said before.

Comment: Well, then that's the problem, you can't convert an array directly into a dictionary. What do you want to achieve by putting the data into a dictionary?

Comment: The thing is every code i wrote is using the dictionary methods such as [[[self.eventList valueForKeyPath:@"picture"] valueForKeyPath:@"url"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; They working successfully, but when i try to copy it, it starts to work like an array and doesn't work. I dont know how to achieve this. I just want to retrieve recent posts from server and prepend it to my data.

Comment: It sounds like you could benefit from a [review](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/hashtables_vs_arrays.htm) of the difference between a hashtable (that's what `NSDictionary` is) and an array (like `NSArray`). There are lots of google results for "array data structure" and "hashtable data structure" online, so take your pick of articles and blogs to read from -- I link to one above that compares the two structures.